# OpenGL texture vs FBO

Tags: c++, opengl

I am pretty new to OpenGL and just want some quick advice. I want to draw a tiled background for a game. I guess this means drawing a whole bunch of sprite like objects to the screen. I have about 48 columns to 30 rows, therefore 1440 tiles (tiles change depending on the game, so I can't pre-render the entire grid).

Currently on start up I create 6 different FBO (using the [ofFbo](http://ofxfenster.undef.ch/doc/classofFbo.html) class from OpenFrameworks) that act as 6 different tiles. I then draw these buffers, up to a maximum of 1400 times, selecting one for each tile. So there are only ever 6 fbos, just being draw a lot of times. (The buffers are drawn to on start up, and are never changed once created).

```
for (int x=0; x<columns; x++) {
  for (int y=0; y<rows; y++) {

  // Get tile type and rotation from tile struct.
  tileNum = tile.form
  rotNum = tile.rot

  // Draw image/texture/fbo that's stored in a std vector.
  tileSet->draw(x*TILESIZE, y*TILESIZE, TILESIZE, TILESIZE);

  }
}
```

I think I am going about this the wrong way, and was wondering if anyone new the best / optimal way to do this. Think something like an old school 8 bit video game background. Here is an image of my work in progress.

[image: work in progress]

The structures in the background are the sprites i'm talking about, the different pieces are the inny corner, outty (concave) corner, square fill, and straight edge. Sorry for messing around with question.

Comment: I think you must be confusing terms, or you don't understand what a FBO is for. You do not want to have 1440 FBOs in one scene, even more so as you will still have to bring the images on screen somehow (drawing into a FBO only draws into a non-visible surface unless it is incidentially the default FBO). Textured quads are what you want. Also, 5,000 microseconds is 5ms, which is quite acceptable as frame time (corresponding to about 200fps).

Comment: You have edited your question, but you're still not undestanding what an FBO is. And no, a texture is always stroed in video memory and doesn't have to be transfered every time. And yes, you're mistaken, in that I am completely unable to understand your question. Are you maybe talking about VBOs? If you are not sure, look up what these concepts are about and rephrase your question.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback, I thought that might be the case. I don't have 1440 fbos, sorry I misworded that. I actually have 6, that are drawn out up to maximum of 1440 times. 

While 5,000 microseconds is quite good, I still am looking to speed it up a little. The game (with the characters and tile grid full) gets down to 30 fps, which is ok, but I wouldn't mind optimizing. The grid is the slowest part, so I thought it should be the first think I look into. I reworded question, thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand your question. A texture is a (usually 2-dimensinal) image that can be applied to polygons, whereas an [FBO (framebuffer object)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html) is a kind of offscreen buffer that can be rendered into instead of the screen, usually used to render directly into textures. So I don't see where your question could be "textures vs FBOs" in any way, as they're quite orthogonal concepts and using FBOs doesn't make any sense in your example. Maybe you're messing up FBOs with [VBOs (vertex buffer objects)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) or [PBOs (pixel buffer objects)](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html)? But then your question is still quite ill-posed.

**EDIT:** If you're really using FBOs, and that only because you think they magically make the texture they reference to be stored in video memory, then rest assured that textures are always stored in video memory and using an FBO in your case is completely useless.

Comment: I think I see where I am getting confused. I am using OpenFrameworks (http://www.openframeworks.cc/), which I think runs openGL lower down. They have an FBO class, http://www.undef.ch/uploads/ofDoc/html/classof_fbo.html. From using this I assumed that they were some kind of alternative to textures. So what I am stuck on is whether I should be drawing with them or just plain textures.

Comment: @rykardo Their FBO class seems to be a wrapper for OpenGL FBOs and is therefore only needed when you want to render **into** the texture (generate the tile at runtime). For normal texturing use textures. Their FBOs are no alternative to textures, but something more complex, that has a texture internally and can do additional things (render into this texture). But it seems you can use its internal texture just like a normal texture, so if you need its additional functionality, using its texture for texturing shouldn't do any harm to your performance, as this texture is still a simple texture.

Comment: Ok this is starting to make more sense now, thanks for persisting with me there. I should spend some time learning jargon, reading docs etc.

Answer (score 0):

for what your doing I would recommend you just use a standard OpenGL texture.

I think I understand what your trying to do, but FBO's retain far more information than you need and will thus take much longer to render onto your destination (which is an FBO).

Comment: Ok great. Yeah to simplify things a little I just want to draw the same set of sprites a whole bunch of times. Thank you for the clarification there.